# FInd value in K and then shift everthing to the right that amount

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a simple code but cant get it to loop thru the rest of the worksheet. Its suppose to see the value in K then shift the everything to the right that amount and only from that point.

Sorry i left out that it has to continue to 52. So the code will be super long. Looking for a way to make it simple.

```
Sub Findandcut()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For row = 4 To 10000
    
    If Range("K" & row).Value Like "2" Then
        For i = 1 To 1
            Range("K" & row).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Next
     End If
     
    If Range("K" & row).Value Like "3" Then
        For i = 1 To 2
            Range("K" & row).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Next
     End If
    
    If Range("K" & row).Value Like "4" Then
        For i = 1 To 3
            Range("K" & row).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Next
      End If
```

Comment: Your code is missing an ending.. I assume `Next` followed by `End Sub` ?

Comment: The code reads each row, looking for 2,3 or 4 in column K. If it finds one, it shifts the cells (including the number in K) to the right 1,2 or 3 places respectively. That pretty much matches your requirement - **so what is it not doing that you want it to?**

Comment: Tried your code, and it seems to be working assuming your cells values don't contain combinations of your Like condition. However, you are missing  Next row and
End Sub lines at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry i left out that it has to continue to 52. So the code will be super long. Looking for a way to make it simple.

Comment: Just curious how is the data in column K look ? A text "2" , other row : "3", other row : "41" and so on. Please CMIIW.

Comment: The code is looking at the value in K. Once it see that number it will move over that amount. So.. if there is a 4 in K it will grab K and everything to the right and move it to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go out to 52..

```
Sub Findandcut()
    Dim row As Long, i As Long, x As Long
    
    For row = 4 To 10000
    
        x = Range("K" & row).Value
        
        If x > 1 And x < 53 Then
        
           For i = 1 To x - 1
               Range("K" & row).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
           Next
           
        End If
          
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked amazing! Yall make it look so easy. LOL

Comment: Can you explain how that works? For future knowledge for me. If you can


         x = Range("K" & row).Value
        
        If x > 1 And x < 53 Then

Comment: `x = Range("K" & row).Value` reads the current rows value from column K and stores it into a variable called `x`. `If x > 1 And x < 53 Then` tests the value stored in `x` to see if it's greater than 1 and less than 53 - i.e. between 2 and 52. `For i = 1 To x - 1` creates a for loop that instead of running for a fixed number of times like in your code, will run until `i` is greater than `(x - 1)`.